# give me meanging of above things

Tags: java, servlets

meaning of 
request.getSession().setAttribute(),response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"Destination.csv\"");,response.getOutputStream();,out.println()
and why use request.getSession().setAttribute()

my code for related it is
request.getSession().setAttribute("lcrConfigProductionRelData",lcrConfigProductionRelData);
lcrConfigProductionRelData is collection 
and this code present in jsp and it access in servlet
servletCode is
(httpSession.getAttribute("lcrConfigProductionRelData");

Comment: give me the meaning of life!!

Comment: No wonder you got -2 already. Please be less ambiguous in your question and re-format your code ;)

Answer (score 2):

- `request.getSession()` returns the session.
- `.setAttribute("lcrConfigProductionRelData",lcrConfigProductionRelData);` sets the field with the given name to the given value.
- `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"Destination.csv\"");` sends a HTTP header causing the user's to show a download window with a file name "Destination.csv

The session attribute is set so it can be accessed somewhere else just through its name without direct access to the original variable.